# Prevent docker from building the image from scratch after making changes to the code

Tags: docker, docker-build

A docker newbie, trying to develop in a docker container; I have a problem which is every time I make a single line change of code and try to rerun the container, docker will rebuild the image from scratch which takes a very long time; How should I set up the project correctly so it makes the best use of *cache*? Pretty sure it doesn't have to reinstall all the `apt-get` and `pip install`s (btw I am developing in python) whenever I make some changes to the source code. Anyone have any idea what I am missing. Appreciate any help.

My current docker file:

```
FROM tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:python3.6

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
ADD ./app /app

# Run python's package manager and install the flask package
RUN apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get -y install default-jre \
    && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    gfortran \
    libblas-dev \
    liblapack-dev \
    libxft-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /app
ADD ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: Recommended reading: [Best practices for writing Dockerfiles](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/)

Comment: For the code you can use volumes point to your code

Comment: I prefer include code into container only for production. For developing you can mount code inside container

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Once the cache breaks in a Dockerfile, all of the following lines will need to be rebuilt since they no longer have a cache hit. The cache search looks for an existing previous layer and an identical command (or contents of something like a `COPY`) to reuse the cache. If both do not match, then you have a cache miss and it performs the build step. For your scenario, you simply need to reorder your lines to make sure the frequently changing part is at the end rather than the beginning of the file:

```
FROM tiangolo/uwsgi-nginx-flask:python3.6

# Run python's package manager and install the flask package
RUN apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get -y install default-jre \
    && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    gfortran \
    libblas-dev \
    liblapack-dev \
    libxft-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY app /app
```

I've also modified your `ADD` lines to `COPY` because you don't need the extra features provided by `ADD`.

During development, I'd recommend mounting app as a volume in your container so you don't need to rebuild the image for every code change. You can leave the `COPY app /app` inside your Dockerfile and the volume mount will simply overlay the directory, hiding anything in your image at that location. You only need to restart your container to pickup your modifications. Once finished, a build will create an image that looks identical to your development environment.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks so much. The *volume mount* seems like a very good strategy for development as well.

Comment: Could you say more about doing the volume mount? What command do I use for that?

Comment: @NicCottrell when you run the container, it would look like `docker run -v "$(pwd)/app:/app your-image`